# Cassandra WriteTimeoutException exception in CounterMutationStage - node dies eventually

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm getting the following exception in my cassandra system.log:

```
WARN  [CounterMutationStage-25] 2017-07-25 13:25:35,874 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[CounterMutationStage-25,5,main]: {}
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2490) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CounterMutation.grabCounterLocks(CounterMutation.java:150) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CounterMutation.applyCounterMutation(CounterMutation.java:122) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$9.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1473) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2486) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Whenever this happens, CPU goes down to 0% for a minute or so, node becomes unresponsive but recovers after that. 
But eventually, the node will die completely (i.e. the process keeps running, but it will not respond to commands any more, even shutdown does not work, have to kill the process).

Some more information:

- Cassandra 3.9
- G1 garbage collector
- Single Node on Windows Server 2012 R2 (20 Cores, 256 GB RAM)
- using a lot of counters and counter mutations

Things I have tried:

- eleminated all other warnings from the log. Used to have warnings about counter batches being too large, rewrote code to not use batching at all. This eleminated the warning, but not the exception problem.
- migrated to a bigger machine, used bigger heap and fine tuned GC to make sure the problem is not the machine being overstressed. CPU load is < 20%.

Does anyone have an idea what else to do? My main concern is the node dying completely. I am not sure that this exception is causing it but it is the only hint I have...

**Update 1:**

Updated to Cassandra 3.11 and the node does not seem to die any more now. However, write timeouts presists, node is unresponsive for several minutes but at least recovers now.

**Update 2:**

Solved the problem (with the help of a professional consultant). Disc I/O speed on our node was terrible, leading to a growing queue of flush writers. Reason is unknown, I/O speed tests on the drive (Raid 1 SSDs) were actually super good.
Moving the node from Windows to Linux (and configuring it according to http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/recommendedSettings.html) solved the problem.

Real reason for the problem is unknown; might have been Windows per se or just some freak incompatibility with the RAID setup. In any case, Cassandra is only really tested on Linux and it is far easier to find help for Linux setups. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a beefy machine with 20cores and 256GB RAM. Cassandra is a distributed system aimed to scale horizontally. Rather than pushing the load at a single node, try adding more commodity hardware and scale horizontally. Also you can run multiple nodes of Cassandra within the same box.

Atleast try running a couple of nodes within this box to scale from the unresponsiveness. Most often CPU is not the bottleneck for Cassandra. Its the I/O that a single node can perform.

- Check the values on concurrent_writes in cassandra.yaml, I guess based on the recommendation for 20 cores it would be 160 (20 * 8).
- If feasible, try separating the commitlog directory and data directory storage drives.
- Best bet to scale writes is to add more boxes (which could be smaller in configuration).

Comment: I will accept this answer because the problem was actually disc I/O and your advice is quite correct, even though it did not solve our concrete problem.